# using "use strict" and variable scope

Tags: javascript, scope, strict

I've started using `"use strict"` for my scripts recently. One of the behaviors I noticed is that this.`[name of variable]` doesn't work for an object. For example:

```
(function(){
  "use strict";

  window.person = {}
  person.name = {
    first: "first name",
    last: this.first
  }
}());
```

Seems like that strict js doesn't allow it anymore. Why is this removed? Are there any disadvantages?

Comment: What do you expect `this.first` to return?

Comment: [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851/2666313)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a function invoked without any implicit or explicit setting of the context, `this` becomes `undefined`.

If the outer context of your immediately invoked function is the global scope, and that's what you expected for its own context, you can use `.call(this)` to set its context to that of the outer context.

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    window.person = {}
    person.name = {
        first: "first name",
        last: this.first
    }
}).call(this);
```

Irrespective of the strict/non-strict mode, `this` will never be a reference to the object being created using the literal notation. That's just how JavaScript works.